# Why angularjs is not showing values with typescript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have the following page in introduction.html.

```
<div ng-controller="IntroductionCtrl">
  <h1>{{hello}}</h1>
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
</div>
```

My controller for this is in the file-> introductionCtrl.ts

```
module app.introduction{
    interface IIntroduction{
    title: string;
    hello: string;
}

class IntroductionCtrl implements IIntroduction{
    title: string;
    hello: string = "Hello World";

    constructor(){
        this.title = "This is title";
        this.hello = "Hello world!!! ";
    }
}

angular
      .module("app")
      .controller("IntroductionCtrl",IntroductionCtrl);
}
```

and my main module is in app.ts :

```
module app{
    angular.module("app",[]);
}
```

My index.html is ->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Simple Tester</title>

    <!-- Style sheets -->
    <link href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

    <div class="container">
        <div ng-include="'/app/introduction/introduction.html'"></div>
    </div>


    <!-- Angular main libraries -->
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-loader.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-mock.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script>

    <!-- App scripts -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>

    <!-- Introduction -->
    <script src="app/introduction/introductionCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to show results of 'title' and 'hello' in introdction.html.Why not showing ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ["controller as"](https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax) syntax:

```
<div ng-controller="IntroductionCtrl as vm">
    <h1>{{vm.hello}}</h1>
    <h2>{{vm.title}}</h2>
</div>
```

You're setting your values on the controller itself, not on `$scope`, so the "controller as" syntax is probably the way to go.